# Angular Can't get ng-model to work in nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, model

I'm very new to Angular, I've been able to get pretty far in my project but I'm running into a little roadblock.

I want to parse some field data, and then apply ng-model to it so I can work with some conditional logic in the fields. 
I actually do have this working:

Fiddle with HTML logic:
https://jsfiddle.net/sup3rmassvie/ws8r4zm5/

It makes the fields, updates the inputs variable and the conditional logic works! (**set the first field to '1' and then select 'First Choice' in the select)

The problem is that seems super messy and not very easy to port to new files, So what I WANT to do is write it in directives.

Fiddle with Directives:
https://jsfiddle.net/sup3rmassvie/bzkypvoo/

However, I can't get the models (scopes??) to work correctly. I've tried a number of things on my own, but I can't seem to wrap my ahead around what I need to do here to make the ng-model on the newly created inputs in the `gField` directive to work.

*note: I am aware in the second pen all the inputs come out as text inputs, I wanted to get past this part first

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured It Out!

Working Fiddle(still only displays the text element): https://jsfiddle.net/sup3rmassvie/h7uxtr4q/

So in my controller I had to make a reference to the scope with

```
$scope.scopeReference = $scope;
```

Then I passed that to the `<gf-form-fields fields="form.fields" model="scopeReference"></gf-form-fields>`

Then in each directive I used the scope attribute to pass it down as "model"

```
.directive('gfFormFields', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:
        {
            fields: '=',
            model: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><gf-field ng-repeat='field in fields' field='field' model='model'></gf-field></ul>",
    };
})
```

Then in the last directive, I literally just told it "Your scope is now this scope"

```
        ...
        template: "<li class='gf-input'></li>",
        link: function (scope, element)
        {
            var field = scope.field;
            scope = scope.model;
            scope.field = field;

            ...add attributes...

            element.append($compile(fieldInput)(scope));
        }
```

Hope this helps someone!